# How to create content type programmatically with fields and vertical tabs

Tags: nodes, features, entities

I'm creating a module using Drupal7.26 and want to create content type with different type of fields like radio/checkboxes/drupdown and textfields.
I'm following the last comment by Jason Gray in [THIS](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/76228/programmatically-creating-a-content-type-with-file-field-in-a-custom-module) thread and is working pretty well except it is not creating Fieldset, Vertical Tab Group and Vertical Tab when the module is installed.

What I did is:
I have created a custom module to create new Content Type by following [SITEPOINT](http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-a-new-drupal-node-type/) tutorial.
And take the fields array by exporting of the node which I created manually using CCK with all fields that I want.
Now all the fields are showing in my newly created node by installing module, except (Fieldset, Vertical Tab Group and Vertical Tab) which I created by enabling [Field group](https://drupal.org/project/field_group) module.

**NOTE:** 
When I export the content type using feature as (test) it gives me 3 files as bellow:
1 - test.features.field_base.inc (I take fields array from here)
2 - test.features.field_instance.inc (I take instances array from here)
3 - test.field_group.inc (it give me the bellow hook) which I'm not sure where/how to use it.I place it in both MYMODULE.install and MYMODULE.module files both didn't work.

```
    function test_field_group_info() {

    }
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wooho :) here is the [answer](https://drupal.org/comment/7799969#comment-7799969)
I was missing hook_ctools_plugin_api() in my module