# How do I use Features to export a custom content type to a stand-alone module

Tags: features

This is a follow-up on, but not a duplicate of, [Programmatically creating a content type with file field in a custom module](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/76228/programmatically-creating-a-content-type-with-file-field-in-a-custom-module).

As suggested by Tenken in a comment to the OP of that question, it is easy to do this by using the core **FieldUI** module to create the fields, and then then use [**Features**](http://drupal.org/project/features) to export the fields to a custom "Feature" module.

You can then install the "Feature" module as any other module that implements a custom content type, but you need to have **Features** installed for it to work.

I want to use the **FieldUI** and **Features** to create a custom content type module, but the module should be stand-alone (i.e. not depend on **Features** for (re)creation of the content type).

Is this doable? Or is **Features** a dead end in my use-case? I.e.: If I want a *stand-alone* module, I must create it from scratch.

And if it makes sense to use **Features**, what do I need to do in order to transform the "Features" module into a stand-alone one?

(I've searched for similar questions, but not found an answer that describes how you make the generated "Features" stand-alone.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The features eco-system simply implements certain hook functions (like `hook_field_info` for example). It wraps these core api functions with import/export code.

When you export your content type using Features you can inspect what it creates -- besides a `mymodule.install` and `mymodule.module` files.

By examining the hooks the features implements for your exported content type -- there is nothing stopping you from copying/renaming these exported function definitions and migrating them to a new module's `hook_install()` function. Thus, creating a new content type which you used Features to create the building block(s).

Comment: Sorry, I meant that in the simplest sense a Module is a folder with a `.info` file. When you export just a content type + it's fields using Features it makes the minimum drupal hooks to represent that data. That does not necessarily include a `hook_schema` function because Drupal `fields` are de-normalized and re-used across content types.